# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I don't know why it says I have an error but this is the exact error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at org.com1027.cw1.rc00182.Salary.main(Salary.java:8)"
```

Here is the code:

```
package org.com1027.cw1.rc00182;

public class Salary {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}   
public double salary; //this is the field I have created within the Salary class with type double 
public Salary() { //this is the default constructor
}

public double getsalary() { //Here is the getter for salary class with a return 
    return salary;
}
public double setsalary() { //Here is setter for the salary class with a return 
    return salary;
}

public int calculateTax()
{
    int salary = 16475; //here I am stating the salary using an integer because it is number related
    int taxSalary = 7035; //here I am declaring the result so I can use it later
    int personalAllowance = 9440; //here I am declaring the personal allowance is equal to 9440
    int taxThreshold = 32010; //this is the tax threshold value I have put in for later use when continuing the if statement 
    int lowerTax = 20; //this is the lower tax and because the value holds a decimal I have used a type double. this will come to use when continuing the if statement calculating the tax 
    int higherTax = 40; //this is the higher tax and again used a type double due to the use of a number holding a decimal
    // above are the 6 variables I have created for the if statement below

    if (salary > personalAllowance){ //here I am saying if the salary is more than 9440 (personal allowance) then..     
        taxSalary = salary-personalAllowance; //this is saying the salary (16475) minus personal allowance gives the result (7035) which is the taxable salary
        taxSalary = 0;
    }

    if (taxSalary < taxThreshold) {
        taxSalary = taxSalary * lowerTax;
    }   
      else {
        taxSalary = (taxSalary - taxThreshold) * higherTax + taxThreshold;
      }

}
```

Also says I have an error on the brace right at the bottom saying I need to put another one in there but I cant find where it is missing from.

Comment: It means you're trying to run code that can't be compiled, something that you should never do. Instead get it to compile first. Look carefully at the compilation errors, and fix those before running the program.

Comment: Looks like an intro programming assignment. Your set and get methods are the same... but fix that :)

Comment: you've missed the closing `}` of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your setSalary() supposed not to do anything or is there additional code, which you forgot to include?

In general a setter should be as follows, though obviously you could make it return a value or a boolean:

```
public void setsalary(double salary) {  // setSalary would have been more readable
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

EDIT: As others pointed out, you are missing a class bracket. I have provided a possible location for it.

```
     else {
       taxSalary = (taxSalary - taxThreshold) * higherTax + taxThreshold;
     }

     return taxSalary;  // <--- missing a return statement here
  }
```

} // <--- Missing a class closing bracket here.

Comment: i really dont know i was doing what the instructions said. il do what you said. never done programming until this so please dont judge me lol

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains bugs. You forced the compiler to compile it. However it cannot. So when you try to run it. It will stop and say that the compiled Java file is not valid. I'm not going to search for your errors in the code. Use an IDE like Eclipse, it will tell you where your errors are and what the problem is.

Comment: never done programming before I started last night and its driving me nuts and im already using eclipse. it says i need to include a brace but i dont know where